# Cannot create Template holding Objects

Tags: c++, templates

been holding off on asking this question for a while, hoping to find the answer, but while I can find similar subjects, nothing seems to answer this for me.

I have been tasked(college) with storing ints, chars and Employee objects in a template class and to order them by their value. The ints and chars haven't been a problem, they worked wonderfully, but I can't get the Employees to be accepted by the template constructor. I've only just begun on templates earlier this week, hopefully someone with greater knowledge can let me know what I am doing wrong/missing.

```
class Employee {
public:
  Employee(string, double);

  string getName();
  double getSalary();

  bool operator <(const Employee &);
  bool operator >(const Employee &);
private:
  string name;
  double salary;
};

Employee::Employee(string s, double d) {
  name = s;
  salary = d;
}

template<typename T>
class triple {
public:
  triple(T e1, T e2, T e3);
  T minimum();
  T median();
  T maximum();
private:
  T firstElement;
  T secondElement;
  T thirdElement;
};

template<typename T>
triple<T>::triple(T e1, T e2, T e3) {
  firstElement = e1;
  secondElement = e2;
  thirdElement = e3;
}
```

My first question, trying to just show the required code, hope that's alright. I assume I'm not supposed to just paste everything here.

```
void main() {
  triple<int> tint(3, 1, 2);
  triple<char> tchar('b', 'a', 'c');
  Employee mark("Mark", 20000);
  Employee tom("Tom", 30000);
  Employee ed("Ed", 40000);
  triple<Employee> temp(mark, tom, ed); //This is giving me an error
}
```

I am being told that there is "no appropriate default constructor available". When it comes to trying to create the "triple" with Employees. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any class data members that are not explicitly-initialized in the *member-initializer list* are default-initialized. The member-initializer list is the part that follows the parameter list of the constructor and comes before the body:

```
X::X() : a(), b() { }
//     ^^^^^^^^^^
//    this part here
```

Your `Employee` class has a user-declared constructor that is not a default-constructor, and because of that the default-constructor for your class that would normally be provided by the compiler is undeclared. This causes a compilation error because there is no default-constructor to call.

Prefer using the member-initializer list to initialize your data members. Inside the body it becomes assignment which is not always what you want:

```
template<typename T>
triple<T>::triple(T e1, T e2, T e3)
  : firstElement(e1)
  , secondElement(e2)
  , thirdElement(e3)
{ }
```

Or you can just give your `Employee` class a default-constructor, that will also work:

```
class Employee {
public:
  Employee() { } // or Employee() = default for >=C++11
  Employee(string, double);
```

Also, consider taking your parameters by reference to `const` since you are just trying to make a copy:

```
template<typename T>
triple<T>::triple(T const& e1, T const& e2, T const& e3)
  : firstElement(e1)
  , secondElement(e2)
  , thirdElement(e3)
{ }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use the constructor in the triple class as you don't use an initializer list a default object of type T is created then the body of the constructor is executed where you replace each of the elements.

As the employee doesn't have a default constructor this fails.

Instead write the constructor for triple using a member-initializer list like so.

```
template<typename T>
triple<T>::triple(T e1, T e2, T e3)
  : firstElement(e1), secondElement(e2), thirdElement(e3)
{}
```

In this case that first default object doesn't need to be constructed so the `Employee` class doesn't need a default constructor.